# I can't figure out why my "Cake" gameobject isn't being destroyed in C#. I've messed up somewhere but don't know the solution (I'm pretty new)

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, encapsulation, destroy

We are learning about encapsulation right now so I have 2 pieces of code that I'm meant to relate to one another however I don't know what went wrong. It's a drag and drop game basically and when you drop the cake it is supposed to be destroyed however it is't currently. The `CakeEvents` Code is connected to the cake, and the `BinLid` is the code that makes the bin open before you drop the cake in it.

CakeEvents:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CakeEvents : MonoBehaviour {
    private BinLid binLid;
    private bool shouldDestroy; 
    [SerializeField]
    private Camera myCamera;
    private bool isDropping;
    public bool IsDropping {
        get { 
            return isDropping; 
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () {
        binLid = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("BinLid").GetComponent<BinLid>(); 
        isDropping = false;
        shouldDestroy = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void OnMouseDrag() {
        isDropping = false;
        Vector3 newPosition = myCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint (
            new Vector3 (Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 10));
        this.transform.position = newPosition;
    }

    private void OnMouseUp() {
        isDropping = true;
        if (shouldDestroy == true) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

BinLid:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


public class BinLid : MonoBehaviour {
    private bool cakeDropped; 
    private CakeEvents cake;

    public bool CheckLidOpen() {
        if (this.gameObject.transform.rotation.z == 0) {  
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    private void OpenLid() {
        this.gameObject.transform.Rotate(0,0,-60); 
    }

    private void CloseLid() {
        this.gameObject.transform.Rotate (0,0,60); 
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other) { 
        bool isOpen = this.CheckLidOpen();
        if(isOpen == false) {
            this.OpenLid();
        }
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    private void Start () {
        cake = GameObject.Find ("Cake").GetComponent<CakeEvents> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update () {
        bool isOpen = this.CheckLidOpen ();
        cakeDropped = cake.IsDropping; 

        if (cakeDropped && isOpen) {
            this.CloseLid ();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a single line where you set `shouldDestroy` to `true` which is what you need since you are checking if it is true before you destroy.

Comment: Hey TyCobb, I still don't know where I can set it to true because it requires the conditions isOpen and cakeDropped I would need to set it to true in Update in the BinLid code. But if i put it there it says it doesn't exist in that context. Thanks for responding :)

Comment: You'll need to make shouldDestroy public or turn it into a property (like IsDropping) to be able to access it from the BinLid class.